# Fix capitalization in a string, then compare it to the orignal strinng

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that fixes the capitalization of a sentence, and then counts how many words were fixed. I'm attempting to do this by copying the original string into a new one, splitting that string, making it all lowercase, then using the ".capitalize()" function on it, and then looping through both the new and original strings and comparing them to count what changed.

Here is my code:

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
    count = 0
    newStr = usrStr.split('.')
    for i in newStr:
        newStr.append(i.lower())
        newStr.append(i.capitalize())
        newStr = ''.join(newStr)
    for new, usr in zip(newStr, usrStr):
        if new != usr:
            count += 1
```

I've run into error after error and am reaching my wit's end. Here is my latest error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like all of my errors have been coming as type errors and I'm quite confused, as I clearly split the newStr into a list before appending.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: you are converting your list "newStr" to string in this line newStr = ''.join(newStr)

Comment: @Sach I didn't realize that was in the loop as well haha. Thank you!

Comment: why not simply `return sum( x[0].islower() for x in usrStr.split())` - capitalize does not respect grammer - it simply upper()s each words 1st character. So your result is equal to counting (summing ones) for each word that starts lower case. This should be faster then creating/comparing all those strings ... and maybe the function should be named 'CountLowerCaseWords' or smth.?

Comment: @PatrickArtner .capitalize() capitalizes the first word in a string. So I'm lowering all of the strings, and then applying .capitalize() to them to make them grammatically correct. (At least that's the intent haha)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation happens through '+' or join function and not append for strings. You can try it by:
`newStr+=i.lower()` 
     or
`newStr = newStr + i.lower()` or `newStr.join(i.lower())`

Answer (score 0):

Error was coming because you are converting list to string in the loop. below code should resolve your error.

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
    count = 0
    newStr = []
    newSentance = []
    for i in  usrStr.split('.'):
        newStr.append(i.capitalize())
    newSentance = '.'.join(newStr)
    for new, usr in zip(newSentance, usrStr):
        if new != usr:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `append` to a string object which is immutable saying any changes to the immutable objects it will create a new object. You can concatenate strings using `+` operator. I believe you can convert it to two lists and then compare

```
def fix_capitalization(usrStr):
    count = 0
    usrStr = usrStr.split('.') #create a list
    newlist=[]
    for i in usrStr:
        newlist.append(i.lower().capitalize())

    newStr1 = '.'.join(newlist) # convert list to string again

    for new, usr in zip(usrStr, newlist):
        if new != usr:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Test

```
fix_capitalization('Test string.mY another String.Correct string')
```

**Output**

1